# How to get the Number of Months in filtered view as a Calculated Member with MDX in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have to insert a calculated member into an existing OLAP-cube and (sadly) do not really know what i am doing.

The result is to be the number of matching months in the current filtered view.
I get the result of months respecting the selected year, but not the filterlist of months.

I have:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[AnzahlMonate] AS 
COUNT(Descendants(
     [Datum].[Datum - J - M - T].CurrentMember, 
     [Datum].[Datum - J - M - T].[Monat]  ),EXCLUDEEMPTY )
,FORMAT_STRING = "0", 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

I get:

[image: Results in SSMS]

I want to get: 
[3]

I tried google, etc. but obviously missing the correct keywords.

Help is much appreciated. thanx in advance.

--

I am using:
SQL-Server 2014
SSMS 12.0.2456.0
Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

I think your measure is calculating the number of matching months without paying any attention to other dimensions used in the filters/slicer. So you get 12 every time.

You are using the keyword `EXCLUDEEMPTY` but you are not telling the MDX *what would make a month empty*. The MDX is looking at the top-level view of your cube. In fact, it is not looking at the numbers in the cube at all, it is just looking at how many members are in the [Datum] dimension.

Edit your answer to tell us the full MDX you are using, and we might be able to help more.

Comment: Hi Magnus, thanx so far. I would like to give you more info. As far as i know i am not using "more" MDX to get a result.
If i remove the year=2017 filter. i get all members of the month level = 120.
How do i get the MDX to look at the cube?

If i dont get this right i would add a column "201708,201707,..." into the view to make a distinctcount(month). Since i might not get the MDX running, this is my goto solution as a last option.

Comment: Sorry, I realise now that you are using MDX to create a new measure on the cube, so you are right there is no "more" MDX. My answer is still the same: you are just counting how many members are in that level, regardless of the filters in use. I am sorry I cannot see how to help you further than that.

Comment: Well thanx anyway.

I will try to find a way, to respect the active filter.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
COUNT(EXISTING Descendants(
     [Datum].[Datum - J - M - T].CurrentMember, 
     [Datum].[Datum - J - M - T].[Monat]  ) )
```

instead of

```
COUNT(Descendants(
     [Datum].[Datum - J - M - T].CurrentMember, 
     [Datum].[Datum - J - M - T].[Monat]  ),EXCLUDEEMPTY )
```

If that does not work, you could try

```
COUNT(EXISTING [Datum].[Monat].[Monat].Members  ) )
```

And if all else fails, another solution would be to add another measure group based on your date dimension table, and define a measure in it which would be the DistinctCount of the month id column.

Comment: Thanx. But sadly i get the same results aas before.

Comment: How does the query that you use for testing the result look like?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working for me when I used GUI-designe, because filter is out of current context:

```
with member [Months] AS 
sum(existing [Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Month].MEMBERS
,count(existing [Date].[Year Qtr Month].CurrentMember))

select [Months] on 0
FROM ( SELECT ( 
{ [Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Month].&[2018-03]
, [Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Month].&[2018-04]
, [Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Month].&[2018-05] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Some_Cube]) WHERE ( [Date].[Year Qtr Month].CurrentMember)
```

But works when I manually added filter:

```
with member [Months] AS 
sum(existing [Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Month].MEMBERS
,count(existing [Date].[Year Qtr Month].CurrentMember))

select [Months] on 0
FROM [Some_Cube]
WHERE
{[Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Month].&[2018-03]
,[Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Month].&[2018-04]
,[Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Month].&[2018-05]}
```